# procrun in --StartMode=Jvm running main that throws exception does not terminate

Tags: java, windows-services, procrun

Trying out [Apache procrun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) I see a behaviour that I do not understand. It boils down to the `main` method of the Java program throwing an exception. This is not logged anywhere and the Windows service does not stop. To investigate further I changed the `main` method to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  if (args.length<10000000) {
    throw new Exception("one exception right away");
  }
  ...
}
```

When I install this as a service with `prunsrv.exe` and then start it, it starts without problems and produces no log output whatsoever. In particular the service does not stop.

For reference, here is how the service is installed with procrun:

```
& $procrun "//$operation//$service" `
  --DisplayName="$service" `
  --Description="$service" `
  --DependsOn="$depends" `
  --Startup=auto `
  --Install="$procrun" `
  --Jvm="$JVM" `
  --Classpath="$cp" `
  --Environment="PATH=$env:JAVA_HOME\bin" `
  --JavaHome="$env:JAVA_HOME" `
  --StartPath="c:\Search" `
  --JvmOptions="-Xmx512M;-Xms512M;-Djava.awt.headless=true" `
  --StartMode="jvm" `
  --StartClass="$classname" `
  --LogPath="c:\Search\std-logs" `
  --LogPrefix="procrun-$service" `
  --LogLevel="Debug" `
  --StdError="c:\Search\std-logs\stderr-$no0" `
  --StdOutput="c:\Search\std-logs\stdout-$no0" `
  --StartParams="(unused)"
```

I would have expected that the service stops right away and I find some log output in the stderr/stdout files, but nothing. Can anyone explain this?

EDIT: Oh my, it seems like `procrun` swallows `java.lang.Error` (in my case `java.lang.noClassDefFoundError`) instead of screaming, shouting and exiting.

Answer (score 1):

After I wrapped a `catch(Throwable)` around the main, logging whatever popped out and then exiting without re-throwing, I saw the problem. I got a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Bottom line: `procrun` seems to swallow error type exceptions and does not even terminate if one is thrown in the called Java program.

Created an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DAEMON-344